# Sending requests when user answer "App wants to use location services"

Tags: objective-c, ios, core-location

I'm using Core Location in my app, app asks user if he wants to use Location services, but I use in my app async requests, so app doesn't wait while user answer "Ok" or "dismiss". Ho can I prevent this? I want that my request will be send when user taps "OK". Thank you

Comment: Are you creating your own Location Services alert? If not, the built-in "Do you want to allow this app to find your location" alert won't get the user's location until they click OK.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In iOS 4.2 and up, your delegate will receive a message `locationManager:didChangeAuthorizationStatus:` when the authorization status changes (i.e. the user responds to the dialog, or the user backgrounds your app and goes into Settings and changes the global location settings). If you support earlier versions, you'll have to fall back to guessing based on `locationManager:didUpdateToLocation:fromLocation:` and `locationManager:didFailWithError:` messages (especially the NSError code `kCLErrorDenied` in the latter).